# Getting hostname aliases from IP

Tags: c++, ipv6, aliases

I want to get the list of aliases for a hostname in C++. This input is a IP. Currently we call `gethostbyaddr()`, which returns a hostent struct. This struct has a field for list of aliases.

```
     struct  hostent {
        char    FAR * h_name;           /* official name of host */
        char    FAR * FAR * h_aliases;  /* alias list */
        short   h_addrtype;             /* host address type */
        short   h_length;               /* length of address */
        char    FAR * FAR * h_addr_list; /* list of addresses */
};
```

gethostbyaddr() API is legacy, and also we wanted to support IPv6 inputs. So we replaced gethostbyaddr() with `getnameinfo()` as recommended in msdn. But after this changes, there is no way to get the list of aliases for a hostname. getnameinfo() simply returns the hostname as a string, and there is no alias list returned by it. Can somebody help me to get the alias list in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible.  The DNS stores:

- for each name, one or many IP/IPv6 addresses;
- for each IP/IPv6 address, up to one "canonical" name.

So you can query the addresses associated to a name (`getaddrinfo`), or the canonical name associated to an address (`getaddrinfo`), but there's no way to query the set of names that map to a given address.